# D3D11 how to get the video chipset model

Tags: gpu, direct3d

Since the convenient IDirect3D9::GetAdapterIdentifier is gone how does one come to get the name of the video card model as string? Having a huge switch with the DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC's VendorId + DeviceId doesn't sound very convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Description` member of `DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC` provides a string for describing the video card. On my machine, I get:

```
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
```